# PHP preg_match split string separated by addition sign

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I'm confused about a `php` regex that needs to **extract two queries** separated by a `+` **plus sign** sentences from a search request (which may include numbers and/or special characters).

Can anyone shed some light on this behaviour?

```
$string = 'string1+String-2';

([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+[a-zA-Z0-9-_])

Array
(
    [0] => string1
    [1] => string1
)
```

Comment: Why don't you use two match groups `(..)` then? Or split/explode if no assertion is necessary?

Comment: `+` has special meaning in regular expressions. If you need ordinary + you have to escape it as `\+`.

Comment: Please post your actual code, not just an abbreviation of it. i.e. Where is the actual call to a  preg function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it this way

```
/([\w-]+\+[\w-]+)/
```

the unescaped `+` behind the square brackets say: "the expression before one or more times"
the escaped `\+` stands for a pure `+`.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way is to use `explode()`

```
$string = 'string1+String-2';

$parts=explode("+",$string);

print_r($parts);
```

with output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => string1
    [1] => String-2
)
```

See more here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: I'm looking for a pure `preg_match` solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the function [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

Your pattern `([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+[a-zA-Z0-9-_])` is mMatching anything that is a letter or number one or more times, followed by a letter or number.

So it is matching on `string` followed by `1`. The output you see is the function doing what it says it does.

> If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search.
> $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern,
> $matches[1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) will have the text that matched the first captured
> parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

I'm guessing you probably meant to use preg_match_all to get all the matching patterns.